# Rails + Cucumber/Selenium: How to type text into <div>?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium, cucumber

I have a `<div class='blah'></div>` on my page and I use javascript so that on click you can type into it (it still remains as a div though). How would I tell cucumber to type into it? `fill_in` doesn't work because it looks for a text field.

Comment: `fill_in` expects you to be filling in a form such as a text box so it won't work.  Your only real option is to select the div through css or xpath and then set the contents of the div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

I think the only way to do this is executing javascript in the step definition:

```
plain_text = "$('.#{hallo_section}_html').val('this will get replaced');"
page.driver.browser.execute_script(plain_text)
```